# TypeError: Cannot read property 'abiDefinition' of undefined

Tags: solidity, web3js

When I run my code ，it told me that

`“TypeError: Cannot read property 'abiDefinition' of undefined”`

The error code is：

`console.log(calcCompiled["info"]["abiDefinition"]);`

The code that I am using is:

```
let source = "
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Calc { 
  uint count; 

  function add(uint a, uint b) returns(uint){ count++; return a + b; } 
  function getCount() constant returns (uint){ return count; }}

"; 

let calcCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source); console.log(calcCompiled); 
console.log("ABI definition:"); 
console.log(calcCompiled["info"]["abiDefinition"]);
```

What should I do？

Comment: What you should do is format your post, provide more code so that we know what you are doing.

Comment: here is my code：let source = "pragma solidity ^0.4.0;contract Calc{    uint count;  function add(uint a, uint b) returns(uint){    count++;    return a + b;  }    function getCount() constant returns (uint){    return count;  }}";
let calcCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(source);

console.log(calcCompiled);
console.log("ABI definition:");
console.log(calcCompiled["info"]["abiDefinition"]);

Comment: Do you have a proper web3 object?

Answer (score 1):

The method `eth_compileSolidity` which `web3.eth.compile.solidity` relies on is [deprecated](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3793) and does not exist nor is available anymore.

An alternative is to compile using [`solc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc):

```
solc --abi Calc.sol -o ./build
```

which generates the ABI file:

```
├── Calc.sol
├── build
│   └── Calc.abi
```

Or compiling with solc in node.js:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const solc = require('solc')

const input = fs.readFileSync('Calc.sol')
const output = solc.compile(input.toString(), 1)
const abi = output.contracts[':Calc'].interface

console.log(abi)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the latest version of solidity, Use the Following code syntax

```
const path = require('path'); //used for getting the path of the file


const fs = require('fs');//used for interacting with the test network

const solc = require('solc');//solc is a compiler for solidity

const CalcPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Calc.sol'); //path to the contract

const CalcSource = fs.readFileSync(CalcPath, 'utf8'); //read the file



 const input = {
 language: "Solidity",
 sources: {
  "Calc.sol": { //name of the file
  content: LottrySource,
  },
 },
 settings: {
   outputSelection: {
     "*": {
       "*": ["*"],
     },
   },
  },
 };
 module.exports = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts[
    "Calc.sol"
  ].Calc; //compile the contract and return the abi and evm
```